# Please explain devi as Supreme Para brahman. Only devi.. Devi only..nothing else

Tags: devi, shakti, shaktism, devi-bhagavata-purana

Devi bhagvatam says"everything merges back into Moolprakriti after mahapralaya.She is the real supreme tatva according to vedas and then after only Parashakti remains".Then my question is what happens to her consort after maha-pralaya, If every shakti and materials including Durga and Sri krishna(Gopalsundari) merges back into Moolprakriti then, does Shiva(Bhuvaneshwara Mahadev) also merges back into Mool Prakriti Srimad Bhuvaneshwari? Note- My view is,at the time of creation Devi appears and transform her right part into Shiva and everything else. And during maha-pralaya everything merges into her including shiva,and devi only remains! Means she closes her eyes!!! That's my view. Now please say is this right Or wrong or if u have ur own views then also answer plss.

But..Answer me as only Devi bhakta!!! as a SHAKTA!!!  Because I can't resist anything beside Devitva. Plss

Comment: Not completely. Something is incomplete.

Comment: If you have time you can go through the following answers: (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20742), (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11034), (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20284), (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18879),

Comment: Bhuvaneshwari and Bhuvaneshwara are basically one soul. So if they merge they will become genderless being. Ardhanareshwara would be a fine example in saguna swaroopa but in Nirguna there is no devi to dev only nameless Parambrahma.